# Outlook 2016 How do you change the format of the TO: field in new emails?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

If you already have the recipient in your contact list outlook will display just the name of them recipient i.e.

TO: `John Doe`

Is there a way I can make it format the TO: field so it will also display the recipients full email address? i.e.

TO: `John Doe<JohnD@FakeEmail.com>`

I have been all over the view settings and advanced options, but I can't find anything to change the formatting of the to field in new emails

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Outlook makes use of "Display As" field of the contact's email. Just edit it to suite your needs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Exchange account? Email addresses are not shown for internal (Exchange) messages but do show for external addresses.

You can refer to this explanation in TechNet Forum: [How do I get Outlook 2016 to show ACTUAL email address I am sending to in "To:" fields?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adbedf51-6e45-47e9-86bb-bd08b87bd81c/how-do-i-get-outlook-2016-to-show-actual-email-address-i-am-sending-to-in-quottoquot-fields?forum=outlook)

[How to show email address not just name in From and To fields](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7196cf81-7822-48bd-8ac5-96ae46566255/how-to-show-email-address-not-just-name-in-from-and-to-fields?forum=outlook)