# Outlook 365: Display full email address of senders and recipients within organization

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, exchange, microsoft-outlook-365

Similar to [this question about Outlook 2016](https://superuser.com/questions/1460088/outlook-2016-how-do-you-change-the-format-of-the-to-field-in-new-emails), but for Outlook 365 (aka Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise).

I have successfully used [this](https://www.espacecode.com/en/how-to/spam-prevention-in-outlook-display-the-sender-s-email-address) formula to display the sender's email address if they are outside of my organization. However, I don't have a way to display the email addresses of senders or recipients who are in my organization. I want to see everyone's email address without having to open the full headers of each message. Thank you!

Comment: As I know, Email addresses are not shown for internal (Exchange) messages, as mentioned in the thread you provided.

Answer (score 4):

To add a full-email field:

- Click *View > Add Columns*
- In the *Show Columns* dialog do the following:

  - Click *New Column* button
  - In the New Column dialog specify a name for the new column
  - Choose "Formula" for "Type"
  - Paste this formula into the "Formula" box

    ```
    IIf(InStr([SearchFromEmail], "@") = 0, "", Left([SearchFromEmail], InStr([SearchFromEmail], "@") - 1)+"@"+Mid([SearchFromEmail],InStr([SearchFromEmail],"@")+1))
    ```
- Click OK to return to the "Show Columns" dialog
- Select the new column and move its place in the list
- Click OK to close this dialog.

The senders full email addresses will now be displayed in the
mailing list.

Source:
[How to always show full email address in mailing list?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/5531-outlook-always-show-full-email-address.html)

Comment: Thanks for that info.  
One note; you have a dot at the end of the code that seems to make it inoperable.  W/o the dot it works.

Comment: This works for external emails, but not for internal emails.

Answer (score 0):

Following the process described in https://superuser.com/a/1697442/650496 using the following formula will at least display **MyCompany** (or any other string you like) followed by the name of the sender for internal emails:

**IIf(InStr([SearchFromEmail],"@")=0,"MyCompany: ",IIf(From=[SearchFromEmail],"",[SearchFromEmail]+": "))+[From]**

(Exchange/Outlook does not need email addresses to send emails internally.)
For external emails it will first display the email address followed by the 'display name' if there is one that is different than the email address.

After saving this column/field you can add it and move it just underneath the field 'from'. Then delete the field 'from' and press OK.