# See recipient's email address in Outlook Sent folder instead of their name

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I found a solution for this problem in my inbox but it didn't seem to work the same in my Sent folder, presumably because something in the code needs to change

[Outlook 365: Display full email address of senders and recipients within organization](https://superuser.com/questions/1697428/outlook-365-display-full-email-address-of-senders-and-recipients-within-organiz)

Any idea what I need to tweak in the answer to that question that will make it work in the sent folder?

Comment: There isn't a similar built-in function for the to/recipient address for some reason. Possibly due to there being multiple recipients? It can be done with VBA by adding a property to each message, but that seems unnecessarily difficult...

Comment: Does [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1697428/outlook-365-display-full-email-address-of-senders-and-recipients-within-organiz) answer your question?

Comment: Check this link and see if it helps: https://www.slipstick.com/developer/recipient-email-address-sent-items/