# How do I get Outlook for Office 365 to display the actual TO address of the message

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have a catch all mail box set up for my domain.  I need to have outlook display the address a message was actually sent to, not the account profile name used to download my messages.  I can see the TO address I am after if I dig into the actual message headers, but I have not been able to get them to display on the list view or on individual messages.  Looking for something similar to this, but for the recipient address rather than the senders.

https://superuser.com/a/1697442/107567

EDIT:
I have tried using a modified version of the above formula but I have not been successful in locating a field that has the desired content.

Comment: Is this a business environment, an IT managed domain, or is this a personal account? WHERE in the Outlook UI do you want the email address displayed?

Comment: personal domain, hosted in office 365 as a managed account with GoDaddy.  I am flexible with where the address displays, as long as I can distinguish which address the message was actually sent to without having to open the properties dialog of each message and wade through the headers.

Comment: Have you followed the steps in the guide you linked but tried adjusting the code to reference the To address perhaps?

Comment: I tried, have not been successful in identifying an equivalent field for the TO address

Comment: Can you please add that info to your question? That will make your question more complete, show people what you've tried, and they won't have to read down through these comments to understand your issue completely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no way to display the full email address in the "To" field in the Outlook client.
Reference Links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1314378/how-to-display-full-email-address-in-the-to-field.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/607623/o365-admin-how-to-rule-outlook-to-always-show-emai.

Comment: Both of these links are relevant to exchange and sending messages.  I am looking for something that applies to messages received.

Comment: Perhaps you can hover over the sender's or recipient's name in the email header. A pop-up window will display the email address and other contact details. Or open the email properties by clicking "File" > "Properties" in the email window. You can find the email address in the Internet header section.

Comment: Hover does not work in this case.  The popup contact card just shows the info for the primary mailbox, regardless of which alias the mail was addressed to.    

Open message -> Files -> properties is what I am trying to avoid doing.  So far it is the only option I have found that shows me the value I am looking for.

Comment: At the moment, there doesn't seem to be a better option to meet this requirement.

Comment: I searched in the Outlook feedback portal and noticed that a similar idea had been posted, and hope Microsoft will take notice of this in the future: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/d105d6e6-fc72-ee11-a81c-000d3ae46fcb